# Error when running Spring boot application with Maven: Name for parameter binding must not be null

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

My Spring boot application using Spring boot 1.5.12 and Java 8 executes perfectly fine in my development environment, but when deploying to testing environment, I'm facing difficulties:

I start the application with : mvn spring-boot:run and the execution stops with an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.
```

I did some searches and understand that in order that my repositories methods work, like this one:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.primaryEmail.emailAddress = :emailAddress "
            + "AND u.deleted = 0")
    Optional<User> findByPrimaryEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
```

I need to compile with the "-parameters" option, because I don't put the @Param annotation on the paremeter "emailAddress".

It works in Eclipse since there is an option activated for the compiler, but when I use maven to compile the app outside of Eclipse, the option must be set.

My problem is that in [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom-input), and since I'm using the default spring-boot-maven-plugin in my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

it should manage this compiler option automatically, and it seems it doesn't.

When I compare the spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom and the pom of the [latest version of spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-parent/pom.xml#L599) on github, I cannot see on my 1.5.12 version the

```
<parameters>true</parameters>
```

Do you have any idea of how I can fix my issue?

I will try to replace the spring-boot-maven-plugin with maven-compiler-plugin with the "-parameters" compiler arg, but I would be more confident if I could use the default spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the option "-parameters" in spring-boot-maven-plugin" has probably been added recently, and the documentation is not correct for Spring boot 1.5.12 (maybe it is for Spring boot 2.0.0)

I resolved the issue by configuring myself the maven compiler:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Important: the "-parameters" arg must be set

Answer (score 0):

You need parameter for emailAddress, jpql cant understand what parameter is given.

```
Optional<User> findByPrimaryEmailAddress(@Param("emailAddress") String emailAddress);
```

Try with that!

Comment: In fact, Spring data provide a way to avoid "@Param" annotations, by reading the name of the parameters.
It is possible with Java 8 and the "-parameters" compile flag.